Extra Files (Block Blobs) creating in the copy activity of the Blob Storage in ADF
I have followed the solution given in this thread, copying data is successful but I'm getting the folder names as block blobs which are extra files to the destination storage account:
Source Storage container data:

After copying, target storage container containing the extra block blob files as shown below:

Why those extra files are creating and any mistake in the solution I followed:
Whole Pipeline:

Step 1: Get Metadata activity


Step 2: For each Activity:

Copy Activity inside for each activity:





Do you want to copy the containers in the source storage account as containers in the target storage account? or as the folders in one container of the target storage account?

as the containers not as the folders

But in your target storage account, all are copied as folders in one container? are those folders being also folders in the source as well?

Clear Detail: Source Storage Contains 1 Container >> 11 Folders + 1 File. Same is copied to destination storage account using the above ADF Solution. After copying, I can see that 10 extra files added (Folders came as block blobs).

One of my observation: My source storage account is of type ADLS2 and target storage account is of type GPv2. Is this the reason that the folders are copied again as block blob  to the target storage container? @RakeshGovindula

Hi @RakeshGovindula, This issue is from our end. Some ITS policy has enabled on the resources we deployed, that disturbed the data copy operation in few ways. It is solved now. Thank you - You can post a solution like 1. Make sure the source and destination storage accounts are of same type like ADLS2 or GPv2 2. Make sure there is no access restrictions enabled on both the storage accounts for data read/write operations. Verify the checks thoroughly and then do the copy the data migration.

Thank you, @Jashua Criss, posting our discussion as the answer for the community.
To achieve your requirement, you need to make sure both source and target storage accounts are same which either ADLS2 or GPv2. Also, the use ADLS gen2 linked services for both source and target.

Results in one container:

